# Are there only finitely many quadratically closed intermediate fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a quadratically closed field of characteristic $0$, $α$ an element which is algebraic on $K$ of degree greater than $1$, and $L$ the quadratic closure of $k(α)$. Are there only finitely many quadratically closed fields between $K$ and $L$? Does it depend on α?

I have no idea if it's true or false. If we could prove that any quadratically closed field is the quadratic closure of a field between $K$ and $K(α)$, we would immediately obtain a positive answer.

This question is interesting because it is directly related to some relation of constructability between subsets of the plane $R^2$, see [this article of Joel David Hamkins](http://jdh.hamkins.org/the-hierarchy-of-geometric-constructibility-can-we-go-back/) for more information.