# Is there a quadratically closed field strictly between the quadratic closures of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, and $K'$ the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. Is there a quadratically closed field $L$ strictly between $K$ and $K'$, i.e. such that $K \subsetneq L \subsetneq K'$?

It is a particular case of [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4300311/are-there-only-finitely-many-quadratically-closed-intermediate-fields), so this is inspired by questions about ruler and compass constructions. If we could find some element $r \in K' \setminus K$ such that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is of degree $3$ in $\mathbb{Q}(r)$, then the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(r)$ would not contain $\sqrt[3]{2}$, because the quadratic closure only adds elements whose degrees are powers of $2$, and therefore we could define $L$ as this quadratic closure. The degree of $r$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, if there is such a $r$, is a power of $2$, because we have
$$ [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},r) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},r) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})] \cdot [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2^n \cdot 3$$
so
$$ [\mathbb{Q}(r) : \mathbb{Q}] = \frac{[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},r) : \mathbb{Q}]}{[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},r) : \mathbb{Q}(r)]} = \frac{2^n \cdot 3}{3} = 2^n.$$
We also have the reverse implication: if there is a quadratically closed field $L$ strictly between $K$ and $K'$, then $\sqrt[3]{2}$ must be of degree $3$ over $L$, otherwise it would be of degree smaller than $3$, and there is no element of degree $2$ over $L$, so it would be contained in $L$, and for any element $r \in L \setminus K$, $\sqrt[3]{2}$ would be of degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}(r)$.

To sum up, the question reduces to: is there an $r$ which is of degree a power of $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and which is not polyquadratic over $\mathbb{Q}$, but which is polyquadratic over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$?

You can find the formulas for the roots of a quartic polynomial [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ehab_Shoubaki/publication/47715135/figure/fig13/AS:650837235863553@1532183097137/5-Roots-of-fourth-order-polynomial-equation.png). We see that the solutions are contained in the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ if the intermediate parameter $f$ is an integer or if it is equal to $\sqrt[3]{2}$. So if we could find such an irreducible quartic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and such that its roots are not polyquadratic, we would conclude. But that becomes quite far fetched.

Edit: Now cross-posted (not by me) [on Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409553/is-the-hierarchy-of-relative-geometric-constructibility-by-straightedge-and-comp?newreg=6e5d5310e10242049ae4613eb036df38).

Comment: The subject of the song is the arrival of Quinn (an Eskimo), who changes despair into joy and chaos into rest, and attracts attention from the animals. Dylan is widely believed to have derived the title character from actor Anthony Quinn's role as an Eskimo in the 1960 movie The Savage Innocents.[4] Dylan has also been quoted as saying that the song was nothing more than a "simple nursery rhyme". A 2004 Chicago Tribune article claimed that the song was named after Gordon Quinn, co-founder of Kartemquin Films, who had given Dylan and Howard Alk uncredited editing assistance on Eat the Document

Comment: @StinkingBishop  probably. I wondered about the OP's user name. The song came out when I was in middle school

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has been answered positively [on Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409553/is-the-hierarchy-of-relative-geometric-constructibility-by-straightedge-and-comp) in two different ways. I post here a copy of my solution:
Let $K$ be the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, and $L$ be the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. The roots of the polynomial $P(x) := x^4 + 36x + 54$ are not in $K$, but they are in $L$, and $P$ is irreducible because it is irreducible modulo $5$, hence any root $\alpha$ of it is of degree $4$, and the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is strictly between $K$ and $L$. (I used https://www.alpertron.com.ar/POLFACT.HTM for the calculations modulo 5.)

First, why are the roots of $P$ not in $K$? It is because mod $7$, it decomposes in $(x+6)(x^3+x^2+x+2)$, which are irreducible, and the discriminant of this polynomial is $-5038848$, which is not divisible by $7$, therefore by Dedekind's theorem there is a cycle of order $3$ in the Galois group of $P$ (Again, calculation modulo 7 with https://www.alpertron.com.ar/POLFACT.HTM, and calculation of the discriminant with https://planetcalc.com/8188/.)

Finally, it is in the quadratic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, because we can look at the explicit formula for the roots of a quartic:

[image]

In our case, $a = b = 0$, therefore $e = \sqrt{(27c^2)^2-4(12d)^3} = 11664$, and $f = \sqrt[3]{27c^2 + e} = \sqrt[3]{2^6 \cdot 3^6} = 2^2 \cdot 3^2$. Except that, only square roots and $\sqrt[3]{2}$ appear in the formula, thus the roots are in $L$.

Comment: Nice to know it can be done, but I wish there were some way of solving this that didn't rely on so much nasty computation.

Comment: @MarkSaving The other answer on Mathoverflow seems cleaner, but some steps are missing and I don't know what it would give if we had the full rigorous proof.